# equivalent ways of writing the spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I often see the spectral norm (aka matrix 2-norm, aka largest singular value) written in a few different (equivalent) ways:

\begin{eqnarray}
\Vert A \Vert &=& \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\Vert Ax \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} \\
&=& \max_{ \{ x \vert \Vert x \Vert = 1 \} } \Vert Ax \Vert \\
&=& \max_{ \{ x \vert \Vert x \Vert \leq 1 \} } \Vert Ax \Vert.
\end{eqnarray}

The first is the definition that I'm familiar with.

The second I suppose is equivalent to the first because we can simply renormalize any vector to have unit norm?

I guess the third follows for the same reason the second does (although the choice of norm restriction on $x$ seems a bit bizarre/arbitrary to me)?

Could we therefore equivalently write the spectral norm as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\Vert A \Vert = \max_{ \{ x \vert \Vert x \Vert \leq 5 \} } \Vert Ax \Vert?
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks, and sorry for the basic question!

Comment: The norm you have defined is not the same as the others - the identity operator tells you as much. I suspect it is equivalent though.

Comment: By "The norm you have defined" do you mean the one at the very end of the post, involving the "5" constraint?  OK -- could you explain how the second and third norms are equivalent to the first, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third is equivalent to the second for the following reason: suppose that $x$ is such that $\|x\| \leq 1$.  We then have
$$
\|Ax\| = 
 \left\|\|x\|\cdot A\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\| = 
\|x\| \left\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| \leq
1 \cdot \left\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| \leq
\max_{\|u\| = 1} \|Au\|
$$
Of course, the other inequality holds because $\{x:\|x\|  = 1\} \subseteq \{x:\|x\| \leq 1\}$.

What it comes down to is that in the third definition, we've "pointlessly added" the set $\{x:\|x\| < 1\}$ to our search space from the second definition even though it's impossible to achieve a maximum on this interior.

Your new norm with the $5$ will have the same result as defining
$
\|A\| = \max_{ \{ x \vert \Vert x \Vert = 5 \} } \Vert Ax \Vert
$, which you can see yields a different result from the second.

Comment: Awesome response; thanks!